# changing key trust level (validity) with gpgme

Tags: gnupg, trust, gpgme

[GPGME](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gpgme/) provides information about a key's trust level as the [`owner_trust` field](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gpgme/Key-objects.html#Key-objects) which is of [`gpgme_validity_t` type](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gpgme/Information-About-Keys.html#Information-About-Keys). However, I could not find a function in the documentation or the `gpgme.h` header file that allows me to *change* the validity of a key.

The GnuPG command line tool sure allows to change the trust level of a key:

```sh
$ gpg --edit-key alice@example.com
> trust
```

Does the GPGME library even support changing the `owner_trust` field? If so, how do I use it?

I am using the newest version of GPGME which is `1.16.0` (commit hash `1021c8645555502d914afffaa3707609809c9459`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be possible to use [`gpgme_op_interact`](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gpgme/Advanced-Key-Editing.html) to accomplish this.

The following demonstrates the process with Python bindings, but analogous code should be possible to write with the C API.

```python
import gpg

def trust_at(level):
    done = False
    def interact_cb(status, arg):
        nonlocal done
        if status in ('KEY_CONSIDERED', 'GOT_IT', ''):
            return
        if status == 'GET_LINE':
            if arg == 'keyedit.prompt':
                if done:
                    return 'quit'
                done = True
                return 'trust'
            if arg == 'edit_ownertrust.value':
                return level
        # needed if we set trust level to 5
        if (status, arg) == ('GET_BOOL', 'edit_ownertrust.set_ultimate.okay'):
            return 'y'
        assert False
    return interact_cb

with gpg.Context() as gnupg:
    key = gnupg.get_key(FINGERPRINT)
    gnupg.interact(key, trust_at('4'))
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it lgtm. Will accept as answer if I can get it to run in C++. Currently blocked by this: https://dev.gnupg.org/T5830

Comment: It works in C++ as well. Also, there is the [Gpgmepp library](https://github.com/KDE/gpgmepp) which has a wrapper for changing trust. But the library is a bit to heavy for my project and look unmaintained.